# Customizing pages in Iframe portlet

Tags: iframe, integration, portlet, liferay-6

Is there a way to somehow customize look and feel of pages in Iframe portlet using additional css or javascript ? One answer in **[this question](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4380535)** gives the hint that it is possible but it is not clear exactly how is it possible.

**Environment:** *Liferay 6.1.0, IBM WAS v7.0*

<sub>*I know this can be achieved using Web proxy Portlet but it is not currently a choice due to its own complications.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be make the othere system accept some parameter and do this change. So in your iframe portlet you may pass some parameter to other system like showSpecificBranding and based on that parameter show different style

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but in my case I don't have any control on other systems. May be there is some other workaround or tweak like mentioned in the forums.